# ContractTrapped Error That Affects Additional Messages Over Time

Tags: ink, pallet-contracts

Have you ever seen a **ContractTrapped error that does not initially exist on a deployed contract, but starts later** after some use of the contract, and gets worse over time, affecting one contract message at first, then a second contract message, etc as the complexity of what is on the contract increases? Each affected message is a read-only message. Any idea what might cause this kind of pattern?

Comment: can you provide the code of the contract and the function that is causing the trouble?:)

Comment: Here’s the GitHub for the contract that is getting trapped: https://github.com/GuruKathryn/geode_social_openbrush ... The first message that gets trapped after some use is Get_Public_Feed. The second message that gets trapped later is get_messages_by_keyword.

Comment: Testing this contract on our test net suggests that when we get a contract revert (which is built in to prevent users from doing certain things), it is altering the memory/storage in funny ways. I think contract reverts are creating memory corruption. What I don't know is what to do about it.

Answer (score 1):

Just from a quick look at the code of the contract, I have a candidate for what can be wrong. One problem might be `message_vec` inside the `ContractStorage.` This field is of type `Vec`, which is so called packed struct (more on this [in the ink! docs](https://use.ink/datastructures/storage-layout#packed-vs-non-packed-layout)).

TLDR;

the maximum size of one memory cell (your `Vec` is in one memory cell) is 16384 bytes. Since your `message_vec` holds items of type `Hash` (which I assume is 32 bytes), you can only fit in 511 items (32 bytes is reserved to hold the size of the `Vec` when SCALE encoding). Therefore, after sending 511 messages, the write to this field (to the storage) will panic as the size of the `Vec` would be greater than the maximum size allowed for one memory cell.

This goes for every `Vec` in the contract storage. You must be sure that in such a situation, the storage cell of `Vec` might overflow to not cause panic.

Again, this is just my suspicion and suggestion from a quick look at the code:) LMK if this helped:)

EDIT:

Since you mentioned the message getting contract trapped is `get_messages_by_keyword`, the case might also be that the extrinsic simply 'run out of gas' since you are looping through an unbound vec.

EDIT2:

since you are using A LOT of (potentially) unbound vectors in the storage, I would suspect THIS the most:)

Comment: We will try increasing ref time and proof size for the call in the front end code. We don't have enough data in the unbound vectors yet to overflow any one cell. BUT am I correct that - even if this is not the current problem - I will need to rewrite how I store data on this contract using LazyVec or Mappings in place of Vectors to avoid major problems in the future as users scale?

Comment: yes, you should definitely take that into account. Mapping usage will be more suitable (since LazyVec would still be Packed, if I'm not mistaken). Also, could you expand your question with steps to reproduce the issue (e.g. from beginning when its working to the case when the contract starts panicking, that would be also helpful for the investigation)

Comment: We are able to reproduce the issue by having any two accounts create enough interaction (posts, replies and endorsements). At that point, anyone following a feed big enough (a feed with enough posts, replies and endorsements) will get a ContractTrapped error when they try to use the message get_public_feed. With enough content to return we also get ContractTrapped on get_messages_by_keyword.

Comment: It is not the level of interaction between users in the feed (such as replies to posts or endorsements). It matters the total size of the data being retrieved. That being said, it does not take much data, about 6 posts with a couple of reply posts and a few endorsements will do it. A single post (or message as we call them in the contract) is fairly small.

Comment: Looks like Lazy Vec is un-packed... https://use.ink/datastructures/storage-layout/#eager-loading-vs-lazy-loading

Comment: judging from what you are saying you are retrieving a lot of data from the blockchain in one message - that will be the issue. As per the Lazy vec - the Lazy will point to another storage location (e.g. Lazy is unpacked) but the Vec inside the Lazy will be in one memory cell (so the restriction still holds) - you can also read this under the code block in the link you shared. For the retrieval of the data I would suggest using events, and doing the heavy stuff off-chain (so either reading events or contract state in a loop - do it offchain)

Comment: Got it. I also noticed that ink 5.0-rc just came out and has a StorageVec option. I am going to explore that one also.

Comment: I don't think this is a storage issue (although the upgrades to storage are important) - I upgraded the contract to ink 5.0 where I can use StorageVec (a kind of Mapping), and on relatively little data, submitting a read-only message, we are still getting ContractTrapped BUT ONLY after we have maybe 10 total entries to work with. It is definitely triggering on having a certain amount of data that the message is working with, but the total amount of data that triggers the error is not that big. I tried increasing refTime, proofSize, and executionTime and none of these made a difference.